# Oracle: search for diacritics

Tags: oracle, search, diacritics

In Oracle I try to find all the rows that contains some diacritics in one column. I used something like:
where regexp_like(name,'(Ă|Î|Ș|Ț|Â)','i');

The problem is that it also returns rows that contain the letters without diacritics (A,I,S,T). For example the clause above will return a row that contains "Adrian" as name.
How can I search only for diacritics?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The way diacritics is handled in comparisons and when sorting is a property of the session that depends on the value of NLS_SORT.  See [Linguistic Sorting and String Searching](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28298/ch5lingsort.htm#autoId22)

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be caused by character conversion.
What do you get when you run the query?:

```
select 'ĂÎȘȚÂ' from dual
```